# AG-Grid: Consistently auto-size columns on scroll?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a large grid and would like it to dynamically resize the visible (they are virtualized) columns on horizontal scroll, but I can't seem to make it consistent since it tries to resize before the grid is fully rendered or something...

```
const App = () => {
  const gridOptions = useMemo<GridOptions>(
    () => ({
      suppressColumnVirtualisation: false,
      suppressRowVirtualisation: false,
      processRowPostCreate: (params: ProcessRowParams) => {
        console.log('processRowPostCreate');
        const cols = [];
        params.columnApi
          .getAllDisplayedVirtualColumns()
          .forEach((col) => cols.push(col));
        params.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(cols, false);
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  const data = useMemo<any[]>(() => {
    console.log('Create random data');
    return createRandomGridData(100, 200, { resizable: true });
  }, []);

  const onVirtualColumnsChanged = (event: VirtualColumnsChangedEvent) => {
    console.log('onVirtualColumnsChanged');
    const cols = [];
    event.columnApi
      .getAllDisplayedVirtualColumns()
      .forEach((col) => cols.push(col));
    event.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(cols, false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: '98vh', width: '98vw' }}>
      <AgGridReact
        gridOptions={gridOptions}
        rowData={data[0]}
        columnDefs={data[1]}
        enableRangeSelection={true}
        enableFillHandle={true}
        suppressClearOnFillReduction={true}
        onVirtualColumnsChanged={onVirtualColumnsChanged}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is a live StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dwx6h7?file=App.tsx. The problem is that the grid is not auto-sized on start and when I scroll really fast it doesn't keep up.

What can I do to make it auto-size the columns more consistently?